# View Template Override that is full page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, view, drupal-templates

I need to create a template for a view i've created (which I know how to do) but I don't want the page to be wrapped in the drupal html.php code. I want the resulting page to be only what is in the template file I create.

How do I do this?

I did found this which does what I need for content types `lab`

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if ($node = menu_get_object()) {
    if($node->type == "lab") {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__lab';
    }
  }
}
```

Then created a file called: html--lab.tpl.php

Can this method be used for my view?
does it have to be `if($node->type == "lab")`?
can I use something like `if($view == "viewname")`

Thanks
C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think when you says "created a view" you mean a view + a page display.
So, when you browse to http://mystite.com/mypage, it will show the content of view.

In this case, you can use your code with some small modifications.

```
function yourthemename_preprocess_html(&$vars) {
  if (arg(0) == 'mypage') {        
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__mypage';        
  }
}
```

You will have to create the right .tpl.php file and clear the cache.

Comment: Thanks @lonut_A. I added the above and created the template file but it didn't work. `if (arg(0) == 'qrule')` becuase url is: `domain.com/qrule` and `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html--qrule.tpl.php';` and template file (in the root of my theme folder) called `html--qrule.tpl.php` Any ideas?

Comment: ok.. I think you meant this:  `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html__qrule'; `

Comment: I realised i also need to add a custom alternative `page.tpl.php` for this view display. How do I add that? I tried `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__qrule';` on the next line but that gave an error.

Comment: nevermind.. I got this answer to this `function mythemename_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__qrule';
}
` thanks @clive